# Create new variable based on the Look up table

Tags: r

I want to create a new variable on the data frame that uses a look up table. So I had df1 (dataframe) that has Amount and Term. And I need to create a new variable "Premium" that create its values using the look up table.

I tried the ifelse function but it's too tedious.
Below is an illustration/example

```
df1 <- data.frame(Amount, Term)
df1
#   Amount Term
# 1   2500   23
# 2   3600   30
# 3   7000   45
# 4  12000   50
# 5  16000   38
```

And I need to create new variable the 'Premium' by using the Premium Lookup table below.

```
                  Term          
Amount           0-24 Mos  25-36 Mos 37-48 Mos 49-60 Mos
0 - 5,000         133      163       175       186
5,001 - 10,000    191      213       229       249
10,001 - 15,000   229      252       275       306
15,001 - 20,000   600      615       625       719
20,001 - 25,000   635      645       675       786
```

So the output for premium should be.

```
df1
#   Amount Term Premium
# 1   2500   23     133
# 2   3600   30     163
# 3   7000   45     229
# 4  12000   50     306
# 5  16000   38     625
```

Comment: Can you share the lookup table and df1 with dput?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get to what you want you need to organise the table and categorise the data. I have provided a potential workflow to handle such situations. Hope this is helpful:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- data.frame(
  Amount = c(2500L, 3600L, 7000L, 12000L, 16000L),
  Term = c(23L, 30L, 45L, 50L, 38L)
)

#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#
# functions for analysis ####
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#

amount_tier_function <- function(x){

  case_when(x <= 5000   ~ "Tier_5000",
            x <= 10000  ~ "Tier_10000",
            x <= 15000  ~ "Tier_15000",
            x <= 20000  ~ "Tier_20000",
            TRUE        ~ "Tier_25000")
}


month_tier_function <- function(x){

  case_when(x <= 24   ~ "Tier_24",
            x <= 36   ~ "Tier_36",
            x <= 48   ~ "Tier_48",
            TRUE      ~ "Tier_60")
}

#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#
# Recut lookup table headings ####
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#

lookup_df <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                amount_tier = c("Tier_5000", "Tier_10000", "Tier_15000", "Tier_20000",
                                "Tier_25000"),
                    Tier_24 = c(133L, 191L, 229L, 600L, 635L),
                    Tier_36 = c(163L, 213L, 252L, 615L, 645L),
                    Tier_48 = c(175L, 229L, 275L, 625L, 675L),
                    Tier_60 = c(186L, 249L, 306L, 719L, 786L)
             )

#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#
# Join everything together ####
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#

lookup_df_tidy <- lookup_df %>% 
  gather(mth_tier, Premium, - amount_tier)


df1 %>%
  mutate(amount_tier = amount_tier_function(Amount),
         mth_tier    = month_tier_function(Term)) %>%
  left_join(., lookup_df_tidy) %>%
  select(-amount_tier, -mth_tier)
```

Comment: This solution will require quite some extra coding in case there are either new months or amounts specified. Maybe you could automise your tier coding to avoid this manual step.

Comment: I agree. Would appreciate if you could kindly provide some ideas for automating the tiering process.

Comment: I would use a `regex` approach similiar to the one I have used in my answer. In the end you have the info already encoded in the row names and you have extract that from there.

Answer (score 2):

**Data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(Amount    = c(2500L, 3600L, 7000L, 12000L, 16000L), 
                      Term      = c(23L, 30L, 45L, 50L, 38L)), 
                 class     = "data.frame",
                 row.names = c(NA, -5L))

lkp  <- structure(c(133L, 191L, 229L, 600L, 635L, 
                    163L, 213L, 252L, 615L, 645L, 
                    175L, 229L, 275L, 625L, 675L, 
                    186L, 249L, 306L, 719L, 786L), 
                  .Dim      = 5:4, 
                  .Dimnames = list(Amount = c("0 - 5,000", "5,001 - 10,000",
                                              "10,001 - 15,000", "15,001 - 20,000", 
                                              "20,001 - 25,000"),
                                   Term   = c("0-24 Mos", "25-36 Mos", "37-48 Mos", 
                                              "49-60 Mos")))
```

**Code**

1. Create first the upper limits for month and amount using regular expressions from the column and row names (you did not post your data in a reproducible way, so this regex may need adaptation based on your real lookup table structure):

   ```
   (month <- c(0, as.numeric(sub("\\d+-(\\d+) Mos$", 
                                 "\\1", 
                                 colnames(lkp)))))
   # [1]  0 24 36 48 60

   (amt   <- c(0, as.numeric(sub("^\\d+,*\\d* - (\\d+),(\\d+)$", 
                             "\\1\\2", 
                              rownames(lkp)))))
   # [1]     0  5000 10000 15000 20000 25000
   ```
2. Get the positions for each element of `df1` using `findInterval`:

   ```
   (rows <- findInterval(df1$Amount, amt))
   # [1] 1 1 2 3 4
   (cols <- findInterval(df1$Term, month)) 
   # [1] 1 2 3 4 3
   ```
3. Use these indices to subset the lookup matrix:

   ```
   df1$Premium <- lkp[cbind(rows, cols)]
   df1
   #   Amount Term Premium
   # 1   2500   23     133
   # 2   3600   30     163
   # 3   7000   45     229
   # 4  12000   50     306
   # 5  16000   38     625
   ```